# Unable to detect iBeacons in iOS9. Keep getting CLRegionStateOutside

Tags: objective-c, ios9, ibeacon

I bought a few iBeacons and I followed a tutorial to try to discover them (http://ibeaconmodules.us/blogs/news/14279747-tutorial-ibeacon-app-development-with-corelocation-on-apple-ios-7-8).

It doesn't work.

locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons will always return an empty array.

If I tweak the code slightly, according to answer of this question([locationManager:didEnterRegion not called when a beacon is detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246493/locationmanagerdidenterregion-not-called-when-a-beacon-is-detected)), I will keep getting CLRegionStateOutside

One thing to take note is that I found the UDID of my beacon my downloading a 3rd party app Light Blue. And that Light Blue app can correct recognises all my beacons.

Another thing to take note is that I have no idea what should I put in the identifier field so I just typed a string that is pasted outside the physical beacon.

This is the code:

```
    - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
    {
        NSLog(@"did start monitoring");
        [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
    {
        if (state == CLRegionStateInside)
        {
            //Start Ranging
            NSLog(@"inside, start ranging");
            [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"outside, stop ranging");
            //Stop Ranging here
        }
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        NSUUID *beaconUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"9B2D1BB8-25AA-8EE5-2513-7C140B6B1801"];
        NSString *regionIdentifier = @"MiniBeacon_04193";
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:beaconUUID
                                                                               major:0 minor:0 identifier:regionIdentifier];
        self.beaconRegion = beaconRegion;
        self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry=YES;
        self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit=YES;
        self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES;

        switch ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) {
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
                NSLog(@"Authorized Always");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
                NSLog(@"Authorized when in use");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                NSLog(@"Denied");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
                NSLog(@"Not determined");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
                NSLog(@"Restricted");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
        return YES;
    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
        [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        NSLog(@"You entered the region.");
        [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:@"You entered the region."];
    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
        [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

        NSLog(@"You exited the region.");
        [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:@"You exited the region."];
    }

    -(void)sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:(NSString*)message {
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = message;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
        NSString *message = @"";

        IMViewController *viewController = (IMViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
        viewController.beacons = beacons;
        [viewController.tableView reloadData];

        if(beacons.count > 0) {
            CLBeacon *nearestBeacon = beacons.firstObject;
            if(nearestBeacon.proximity == self.lastProximity ||
               nearestBeacon.proximity == CLProximityUnknown) {
                return;
            }
            self.lastProximity = nearestBeacon.proximity;

            switch(nearestBeacon.proximity) {
                case CLProximityFar:
                    message = @"You are far away from the beacon";
                    break;
                case CLProximityNear:
                    message = @"You are near the beacon";
                    break;
                case CLProximityImmediate:
                    message = @"You are in the immediate proximity of the beacon";
                    break;
                case CLProximityUnknown:
                    return;
            }
        } else {
            message = @"No beacons are nearby";
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", message);
        [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:message];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the code is not looking for the proper ProximityUUID of the beacon.  The `9B2D1BB8-25AA-8EE5-2513-7C140B6B1801` UUID in the code that originated from the Light Blue app is not a ProximityUUID needed to detect iBeacons.

Understand that there are many kinds of UUIDs.  The Light Blue app will detect Bluetooth Service UUIDs but it will not detect iBeacon ProximityUUIDs.  While the superficially look the same, they have different values and meanings.  It may be that the Bluetooth Service UUID you scanned with Light Blue did originate from the beacon, but it still won't work in the code shown, because it isn't the correct ProximityUUID.

How do you figure out your beacon's ProximityUUID?  A few options:

1. Ask the manufacturer, or use the manufacturer's configuration utility.
2. Use a [dedicated beacon scanner for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en), [OSX](https://radiusnetworks.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204984434-What-is-ScanBeacon-) or Linux which lets you see any beacon regardless of the ProximityUUID.  Unfortunately, iOS only lets you see beacons if you know the ProximityUUID up front.

Once you know the ProximityUUID, simply replace the value instead of the `9B2D1BB8-25AA-8EE5-2513-7C140B6B1801` shown.