# Why are monitoring callbacks not called when Airplane Mode is enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, cllocationmanager

Has anyone noticed that monitoring callbacks don't fire when Airplane mode is enabled on iOS? Of course, Bluetooth is also enabled, and even wifi, and I have permissions, but still no monitoring callbacks.

Ranging is actually better when Airplane Mode is enabled, but that only confuses me more, and I can't just say that I'm in a region because it's ranged as X meters away, and that would add so much overhead to every scan, and I'm working with possibly a lot of different beacons.

I can't be the only one seeing this.

Why might Airplane mode stop these callbacks but not didRangeBeacons callbacks?

Comment: A similar but different question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246493/locationmanagerdidenterregion-not-called-when-a-beacon-is-detected David Young's steps are great, but when airplane mode is not on I get the callbacks, and I haven't moved outside the region, so it's not that. Muhammad Ibrahim's steps are good too, but the Notify things on regions start the app when those regions are detected, I just want to get a callback, and it still didn't seem to work when I set these flags

Comment: The error I'm seeing is the "too many regions monitored one" but it's not that either.. ```BeaconHandler: Failed monitoring region: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=5 “(null)“, monitored regions: 1, inRegion = false``` where can I learn more about this stuff? I will be physically sick if you link me to the Apple tutorials

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654305/region-monitoring-while-device-is-in-airplane-mode This guy saw the same thing.. and yet nothing from Apple. The struggle is real

Comment: Apple also say that regions are not available because "The device is in Airplane mode and can’t power up the necessary hardware.". My BLE ranging results disagree with this